# SQL Server 2008 cluster cannot add possible owner to SQL Server/SQL Server Agent Resources

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, cluster-computing

Setting up SQL Server 2008 failover cluster on Windows Server 2008 R2

Created cluster (added 2 nodes `Node1`, `Node2`). Installed SQL Server 2008 on `Node 1`. It installed successfully and service came up. I am able to connect through management tool using virtual IP.

Now when I want to add `Node 2`, instance name is not displayed during installation.

When I further analyzed, I could see possible owners for both resources SQL Server, SQL Server Agent are just Node 1. Whereas other resources have both Node 1 and Node 2.

I tried the thing below.

```
C:\Users\administrator.GENNEYS>cluster.exe res "SQL Server" /addowner:GEN-C7-181

Adding 'GEN-C7-181' to possible owners of 'SQL Server'...
```

> *System error 5079 has occurred (0x000013d7). The specified node does
>   not support a resource of this type. This may be due to version
>   inconsistencies or due to the absence of the resource DLL on this
>   node.*

How should I add another Node to possible owners of SQL Server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Server DLL (SQSRVRES.DLL),SQL Server Agent (SQAGTRES.DLL) was only present on NODE1 under Windows\systems32\ folder. Copy these to NODE 2 same folder. It will automatically add NODE 2 as owner.